# HERE sdk Lite edition for android autosuggest return PARSING_ERROR

Tags: here-api

I'm a user HERE sdk Lite edition for android, mainly using the autosuggest search place feature. My application is already running and functioning properly. To this day problems arise so that they don't work. After I checked it turns out that in the SuggestCallback class section it return PARSING_ERROR. Please help

here is SuggestCallback class:

```
    private final SuggestCallback autosuggestCallback = new SuggestCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onSuggestCompleted(@Nullable SearchError searchError, @Nullable List<Suggestion> list) {
        if (searchError != null) {
            //Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Autosuggest Error: " + searchError.name());
            Toast.makeText(HereMapsActivity.this, "" + searchError.name(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return;
        }


        for (Suggestion autosuggestResult : list) {
            String addressText = "Not a place.";
            Place place = autosuggestResult.getPlace();

            if (place != null) {
                addressText = place.getAddress().addressText;

                datatmp.add(new DataListLocation(
                        addressText,
                        place.getCoordinates().latitude,
                        place.getCoordinates().longitude
                ));

            }else{
                datatmp = new ArrayList<>();
            }

            adapterListLocation = new AdapterListLocation(HereMapsActivity.this, datatmp);
            lstview.setAdapter(adapterListLocation);
        }

        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
};
```

Comment: I've checked one of my examples and it works fine. Can you provide your code?

Comment: We have the same issue since yesterday_ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62690643/here-suggest-api-returns-parsing-error

Comment: @leopectus, I have attached it to my question.thanks

Comment: @michaelsmith, so theres is some think problem on HERE sdk right?

Comment: I have reached out to the SDK team and we're investigating.

Comment: If you could let me know the exact version of the SDK you are using, that would be hepful.

Comment: @leopectus, i used HERE sdk for android (Lite Edition) v4.3.3.0

Comment: It looks like a temporary backend issue that should be fixed soon. HERE team is working on it.

Comment: Just to update you, we are aware of the issue and are working on a fix.

Comment: Update: a rollback is currently in progress and things should be back to normal soon.

Comment: Problem SOLVED, thanks to HERE sdk team support